# How to expand a json for a specified website, based on the url

Tags: json, url

This might be a bit of a confounded question, but please bear with me:

If I were on a site, wanting to read comments through the json, as with this [particular site](http://finance.yahoo.com/_xhr/contentcomments/get_comments/?content_id=60902841-c238-364c-92f0-68e8b4dce996&_device=full&count=10&sortBy=highestRated&isNext=true&offset=10&pageNumber=1&_media.modules.content_comments.switches._enable_view_others=1&_media.modules.content_comments.switches._enable_mutecommenter=1&enable_collapsed_comment=1), how would I expand this particular site such that I can see more than 10 comments? Currently, the ending to the url looks like `/?content_id=60902841-c238-364c-92f0-68e8b4dce996&_device=full&count=10&sortBy=highestRated&isNext=true&offset=10&pageNumber=1&_media.modules.content_comments.switches._enable_view_others=1&_media.modules.content_comments.switches._enable_mutecommenter=1&enable_collapsed_comment=1`.

I tried changing the `pageNumber` to a higher number and got the same results. I tried change the `&count=10` to `&count=50`, which also doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the API you are accessing have documentation? Seems that would be the best place to research how to change your expected result set

Comment: I would have thought the `count` value would do it, and `offset` would let you start with, eg, comment 11.  This is a fairly common "style".  But there's nothing to say that the site pays any attention at all to those values -- it's whatever the site says it is.  (But testing shows it will work if you make `offset` be an integer multiple of `count`.)

Comment: It's not through an API @JasonFingar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each website will be a case by case. Some websites will allow you to expand it at the end of their url, as in:

```
https://somesite.com/search&page=1&resultcount=100
```

where you would change the parameter of resultcount to a higher value. Some sites cap the value at arbitrary values, and some don't have this parameter.